# Two questions about Interaction-terms in IV-regressions (2SLS) in R

Tags: r, panel-data, 2sls

I am doing a 2SLS-model in R with panel data (n=800), where I want to include an interaction-term as Instrumental-Variable in the first-stage model. **My first question is**: Does that even make sense? The idea is that only the interaction term works as a good IV for X on Y.

**1. Stage-model**:

`first_stage <- plm(X ~ (Z(a) * Z(b)) + X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5, data = data, model = "within", effect = "individual")`

As I write above, I am particularly interested to delete "bad" variance of X on Y (2. Stage model), by limiting it to the variance in relation to the interaction-term (1. Stage model).

**My second question** is regarding the second-stage model of my 2SLS-model. Can I, building on the first-stage model, do an interaction between the predicted X (= X hat) and the rest of the independent variables?

**2. Stage-model**:

`second_stage <- plm(Y ~ X_hat * (X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + X5), data = data, model = "within", effect = "individual")`

Here I want to get an insight on what effect the isolated variance of predicted X (X_hat) has in interaction with other variables (X1-X5) on Y.